# angular 6 chat box application and id height

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application, I have chat box where user sends message in the chat window, what happening is that after each send of message I am scrolling down so user can see latest message they can enter, therefore I have below function which helps me partially to achieve same. but after some number  of messages, this does not scroll top so  I can't see latest messages.

```
 function scrollToTheEnd(divId) {
    var $target = $('#' + divId);
    $target.animate({
      scrollTop: $target.height()
    }, 'slow');
  }
```

I have div with `messages`

```
<div id ="messages"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recommended to mix Angular with JQuery. Everything in JQuery could be accomplished using Angular. In this specific case, you could use the [`AfterViewChecked`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked) life cycle hook with a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var). From the docs, the hook is

> called after the default change detector has completed checking a
>   component's view for changes.

So it will be called whenever there is a change in the view.

Try the following:

Template

```html
<div id="divId" #chat>
  ...
</div>

<button (click)="scrollToBottom()">Down</button>
```

Controller

```js
import {Component, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('chat') private chatBox: ElementRef;
  .
  .

  // auto scroll to bottom
  /*
  ngAfterViewChecked() {        
    this.scrollToBottom();        
  }
  */ 

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.chatBox.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.chatBox.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: this.scrollToBottom() is on click button in my code. hope that wont create any issues

Comment: Then you could bind the `scrollToBottom()` function to the button and remove it from the life cycle hook. I've edited the code.

Comment: ok I did it as per you but looks like it is not scrolling at bottom

Comment: This is only to give a basic idea of using native Angular. You might need to tweak it according to your template implementation.